# How to align the xaxis tick mark center

Tags: highcharts

In the given example my first and last bar tick mark placement are not aligned centre.

`Example:`http://jsfiddle.net/geeet0ek/

How to make it align centre?

Comment: The problem exist in single and double bars. Updated the same example.

Comment: first and last plots have 2 bars while in others three bars are there, label render accordingly

Comment: I have added one more bar and its aligned now http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/geeet0ek/4/

Comment: yes, i agree if i have three bars in all the dates the tick mark alignment is centre. But i have to align the tick mark in centre if a date has one or two or three bar in a specific date. Is it possible?

Comment: But it **is** aligned in the center . It is not aligned between the two columns - but it shouldn't be, because the spot for the third column is still there, even though there is no value to display. You can demonstrate that it is centered just like with the other groups, by hiding/showing the 'Closed' series and watching how they move.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment this is not available, because ticks are aligned to group. In your case empty value is null, so takes a place. As a result ticks is in the middle of group. You can post your suggestion in our uservoice [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)